# Where does encodeAsSHA() function came from

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm starting out with Grails and I'm following the InfoQ ebook found [here](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started).

The book teaches about Authentication in Chapter 9 and how to encrypt the password. Below shows how it is done, but I don't understand how it works.

First, we need to create a class in `grails-app/utils/SHACodec.groovy`:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
    class SHACodec{
      static encode = { target->
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA')
        md.update(target.getBytes('UTF-8'))
        return new String(md.digest()).encodeAsBase64()
      }
}
```

Then in my `User domain`, I need to add a closure to `beforeInsert`:

```
class User{
...
String password

def beforeInsert = {
  password = password.encodeAsSHA()
  password
  }
...
}
```

---

The code is working fine, but I don't see the connection on how adding a class in `grails-app/utils/SHACodec.groovy` enable the use of the function `encodeAsSHA()` for `password` in the `User domain`.

Since the `SHACodec` class only assign a closure to `encode`, and never mention `encodeAsSHA()`. How is `password`(a `String`) able to use it out of no where?

I'm surely missing something here!

Answer (score 0):

A Grails codec class is one that may contain an encode closure, a decode closure or both. When a Grails application starts up the Grails framework dynamically loads codecs from the grails-app/utils/ directory.

The framework looks under grails-app/utils/ for class names that end with the convention Codec. For example one of the standard codecs that ships with Grails is HTMLCodec.

If a codec contains an encode closure Grails will create a dynamic encode method and add that method to the Object class with a name representing the codec that defined the encode closure. For example, the HTMLCodec class defines an encode closure, so Grails attaches it with the name encodeAsHTML.